# Issue adding a "$" to a tip calculator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a "$" to a tip result in my app, but I'm having some difficulties. I'm next to Xcode and Objective-C, I am not exactly sure where I need to place the symbol with causing an error. Below is a copy of my .m code.

Any help is much appreciated

```
#import "tipcalcViewController.h"

@implementation tipcalcViewController


- (void)dealloc
{

    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)aSliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    if (slider == tipslide) {
        NSString *tip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", slider.value * 100];
        int tipPercentage = [tip intValue];
        NSString *multiplier;
        if (tipPercentage < 10) {
            multiplier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.0%i", tipPercentage];
        }
        else if (tipPercentage >= 10) {
            multiplier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%i", tipPercentage];
        }
        [costWithTipLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ([[costWithoutTip text] intValue] * [multiplier floatValue])]];
        [tipTextLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tip(%i", tipPercentage] stringByAppendingString:@"%):"]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateNumOfPeop)];
    }
    else if (slider == peopleslide) {
        NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", slider.value*10];   
        int numberOfPeople = [p intValue];
        [numberOfPeopleTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Each(%i):", numberOfPeople]];
        [numberOfPeopleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[costWithTipLabel text] floatValue]/numberOfPeople]];
    }
    [totalBillCost setText:[costWithTipLabel text]];
}
- (void)updateNumOfPeop {
    NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", peopleslide.value*10];   
    int numberOfPeople = [p intValue];
    [numberOfPeopleTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Each(%i):", numberOfPeople]];
    [numberOfPeopleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[costWithTipLabel text] floatValue]/numberOfPeople]];
}
/*
- (IBAction)aSliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    if (slider == tipslide) {
        NSString *tip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", slider.value * 100];
        float tipPercentage = [tip floatValue];
        NSString *multiplier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%.f", tipPercentage];
        [costWithTipLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[costWithoutTip text] floatValue] * [multiplier floatValue]]];
        [tipTextLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tip (%.f", slider.value *100]stringByAppendingString:@"%):"]];
    }
    else if (slider == peopleslide) {
        NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", slider.value*10];
        float numOfPeople = [p floatValue];
        [numberOfPeopleTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Each (%.f):", numOfPeople]];
        [numberOfPeopleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[costWithTipLabel text] floatValue]/numOfPeople]];
    }
    [totalBillCost setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[costWithTipLabel text] floatValue]]];
}
*/
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [costWithoutTip becomeFirstResponder];
    [costWithoutTip setDelegate:self];
    [costWithoutTip setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
    [tipslide setValue:0.01];
    [peopleslide setValue:0.1];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [costWithoutTip setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [costWithoutTip text].floatValue]];
    [costWithoutTip resignFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [costWithoutTip resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [costWithoutTip resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Please use proper Markdown formatting when embedding code: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: One thing I know for sure, the problem is not within `/*viewDidLoad*/` or `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`. You didn't even try to make our (the answerers) life easier by removing code that has nothing to do with the problem. People at stackoverflow aren't machines that spit out answers if you throw a question at them. I can only speak for myself, but I don't want to answer a question that doesn't show any effort by the questioner.

Comment: on which uilabel do you want to show the currency sign?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to format currency, use NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSNumber *someMoney = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.95];

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSString *formattedAsDollars = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someMoney];
[currencyFormatter release];
```

You can even venture into the world of NSDecimalNumber if you're feeling brave.